# bootstrap grid layout for mobile, tablet and desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, grid

I am trying to create an easier UI for people to enter data, for a golf scoring web application. The principle is for large buttons to press for each score, rather than typing them in.

I have created an additional CSS file to make buttons larger than the default...

```
.btn-sq-lg {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
}

.btn-sq {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.btn-sq-sm {
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.btn-sq-xs {
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  padding:2px;
}
```

Currently I have the following, which displays properly on a desktop device (Ignore the "xs" grid cells, this is me playing about. The "lg" grid cells format as I would like...)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">Blob</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">2</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">5</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">6</button>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">7</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How / What is the equivalent to make the same format appear on a mobile device?

I can use alternate (custom) button sizes as needed, just looking for a good steer for the syntax to use...

Comment: Your title does not capture the point of your question. I would go for something like: "Resize Bootstrap buttons to custom size at standard breakpoints" I would remove any html code and classes that are not important to the question, and I would go over the questions body text and try to rewrite it so that it states your current problem, what your snags if any have been and then clearly asks a question that lets us know what you are trying to accomplish and what steps you have taken to try to get there.

Comment: Why the `!important` this is typically reserved for very few cases, but something like a utility class, definitely not a Bootstrap override. Read this:
https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something to take care of all the regular bootstrap breakpoints and target all of those steps in your new button, try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sq">5</button>
    </div>
</div>

/* Anything below xs */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 1px) {
    .btn-sq {
      padding: 4px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 8px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
  }
}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .btn-sq {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      font-size: 11px;
      background-color: pink;
  }
}

/* Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .btn-sq {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 13px;
      background-color: yellow;
      color: black;
  }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .btn-sq {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: green;
  }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .btn-sq {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      font-size: 18px;
      background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Check out my codepen: http://codepen.io/httpJunkie/pen/OVKJPZ
It's not perfect, but it should get you on your way. THe way I see it is that you only need to create your new square button type and set the typical bootstrap breakpoints. There are more clever ways to do this, but this is the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a media query to change the size of the button based on screen size. For example if you are on a cell phone then you need to change your buttons to a width/height of 25px. You can use the width/height of 50px for tablets and the 100px for larger screens.

For example to handle a cell phone you would add this to your css file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .btn-sq {
        width: 50px !important;
        height: 50px !important;
        font-size: 10px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you were instrumental in making this question easier to understand. Because I was having a hard time following the question.